# How to store output from a python file into a variable

Tags: python, terminal, output

I m calling an executable in a python script which gives an output in the terminal as follows:

> Number of Iterations: 150
>
> Average time per step is 0.306834 ms
>
> Average time for collisions is 0.027553 ms
>
> Average time for velocity updates is 0.109900 ms
>
> Average time for position updates is 0.031053 ms
>
> Total loop time is 46.2161 ms

But i want to store this text in a variable so that i can edit it. How to do this???

Comment: `output = Popen(["mycmd", "myarg"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). It lets you redirect the output. You could simply do:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(args)
```